# Python alternate function to fuzz.token_set_ratio to reduce execution time

Tags: dataframe, performance, flask, python-3.8, name-matching

I am working on name matching problem where I have names of customers which need to be compared with 2.5 Million records of existing customers saved in csv file. Below is the code which I tried and its taking 5-12 minutes for single name matching. As this will be integrated as API with RPA process, suggest me any other way to achieve the same within one or two mins.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import time

# names is the list passed to the program as parameter
names_with_sno = [[sno, name] for sno, name in enumerate(names, 1)]

# dataframe created for the given customer names
df1 = pd.DataFrame(names_with_sno, columns=['s_no','SDN_NAME_SERACH'])

# dataframe for customer database via csv
cust_2 = pd.read_csv(r'...\customer-database-extract\extract.CSV')

# .... preprocessing of both the dataframes
# .... which are not time consuming ones

### CROSS JOIN
#doing the cross join between the given names and customer database
#creating common key in the dataframe having the given names
df1["key"]=1

#creating common key in customer db dataset
cust_2["key"]=1

#sdropping the common column key after creating the cross join
final_df = pd.merge(df1,cust_2,on="key").drop("key",1)   

**def get_ratio(df):
    cust_name=df["FIRST_NAME"]
    hit_name=df["SDN_NAME_SERACH"]
    return fuzz.token_set_ratio(cust_name,hit_name)**

st = time.mktime(time.localtime())

#applying the function for name _mtahcing and storing it in a series
**final_series = final_df.apply(get_ratio,axis=1)**

print('\n\nt23 - df.apply(get_ratio) - ',secondsToText(time.mktime(time.localtime()) - st))
```

here, df1 is the dataframe of given name and cust_2 is DB extract read from the csv file. The print gives the time as,

*t23 - df.apply(get_ratio) -  5.0 minutes, 42.0 seconds*

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this?
If my question is not clear please suggest me a better way of asking it, as it is my first question to open forum.

Comment: As a first step you could try to replace the usage of FuzzyWuzzy with [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) which should already reduce the runtime a lot ( I would expect at least a 10x improvement)

Comment: sorry @maxbachmann, I was on vacation for a week, so couldn't track this question... I will check the RapidFuzz and come up with the results... Thanks for your answer, it will help me a lot if it works.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @maxbachmann... Sorry I was on vacation, haven't checked the question for a while... will check the RapidFuzz and get back with the findings... It will help me a lot if it works...

Comment: Apologies, I thought that I have already commented... Thanks @maxbachmann, it has worked, using rapifuzz has reduced the execution time by 3 to 4 times, earlier it was 6 to 8 mins, now it is around 2.5 mins... Thanks for your suggestion.